# SQL - When to use update or join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with data which in one table is being pulled from a third party application and has all the data just dumped. There are then tables where certain pieces of the tables are grabbed and used in other tables.

The two tables involved are called Projects and ALL_PROJECTS. ALL_PROJECTS contains a column called "Is_Ready" which has binary values. I want these values to populate in Projects, where I have created a column also named "Is_Ready".

The unique ID for Projects is a composite primary key consisting of the ProjectID column and the TestID column. The ALL_PROJECTS table only has ProjectID connecting it to the Projects table (And it is not called ProjectID, it is called ProjectCode).

My question, can an update handle this or is a join required? I want the value of "Is_Ready" to be set for each row. There may be a dozen TestIDs with one ProjectID but if "Is_Ready" is for example set to 0 for the ProjectID of 124480 I want "Is_Ready" in every row that has the ProjectID of 124480 in the Project table to be set to 0.

My first instinct was to try something like this

```
UPDATE Projects
SET Projects.Is_Ready = ALL_PROJECTS.Is_Ready
WHERE Projects.ProjectID = ALL_PROJECTS.ProjectCode;
```

However that doesn't seem to be working. Do I have to do a join to to do this, or am I just doing something wrong with my update statement?

Update: Ok, so I added the FROM clause but now I'm just getting 0 row(s) affected.

Comment: just explain in few words what you need. This is not readable. Instead of writing text more you can show your Table Structure here...or a screen shot

Comment: It is always beneficial to make update and insert queries as select to begin with; and then once you get the output, change it to a insert/update. Will save you tons of problems with wrongly modified data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "FROM" part of your update statement. It should be like this:

```
UPDATE Projects
SET Projects.Is_Ready = ALL_PROJECTS.Is_Ready
FROM Projects, ALL_PROJECTS
WHERE Projects.ProjectID = ALL_PROJECTS.ProjectCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the from clause:

```
UPDATE Projects
SET Projects.Is_Ready = ALL_PROJECTS.Is_Ready
FROM ALL_PROJECTS
WHERE Projects.ProjectID = ALL_PROJECTS.ProjectCode;
```